# How to change div on orientation of mobile with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am new in jquery mobile. i want to change HTML on landscape. if user in portrait it show image and text (rotate to landscape), if user rotate his mobile then the main content is show.

Comment: https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Comment: but this is only for text rotation  how to rotate full page. if you want to help me out i send the image that i want to need

Answer (score 0):

In your page have a DIV for the message in portrait mode and then a separate DIV for the regular content in landscape mode:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="head" data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div id="cont" role="main" class="ui-content">

      <div id="portrait">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/180/technics/1/" />
        <p>Please turn your device to Landscape mode</p>
      </div>
      <div id="landscape">
        You are now ready to go!
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Then use the orientationchange event to show the appropriate DIV:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  if (event.orientation == "portrait"){
    $('#portrait').show();
    $('#landscape').hide();
  } else {
    $('#portrait').hide();
    $('#landscape').show();    
  } 
});

$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
  $( window ).trigger("orientationchange");
});
```

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/wevvLB)**

If you run the demo on a PC, resize the window to see it change.